# command line no prompt keytool -genkey -noprompt

Tags: android, xamarin, command-line

is there a way to execute a command from command line that usually asks for user interaction but doing it silently.

I found this googling

```
    keytool -genkey -noprompt \
   -alias alias1 \
   -dname "CN=mqttserver.ibm.com, OU=ID, O=IBM, L=Hursley, S=Hants, C=GB" \
   -keystore keystore \
   -storepass password \
   -keypass password
```

but how do I format it to make it run in the command prompt?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You get the OutputStream from the Process you created starting the command from the application and write to it.

Comment: Not sure I  understand  I am using visual studio 2015 if the helps should I run that as a single line in the ms build prompt is that  what u mean

Comment: Where you trying to run it? In Windows shell or from Android Application?

You can remove the \ and turn it single line if you want